# Why does my paragraph not wrap in my table?

Tags: html, css

For the below code, my paragraph makes my first column (headed by link1) much too long. I have set the `word-wrap` to `break-word`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Is it getting overwritten somehow?

```css
th {
  font-family: "SansSerif";
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: left;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
#table1 {
  border: double;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.para {
  padding: 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>
    Table Test
  </title>

</head>

<body>

  <table align="center" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="5px" id="table1">
    <th><a href="http://www.google.ca">link1</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="http://www.last.fm/user/RomeLeader">link2</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="http://www.wolfparade.com">link3</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="http://www.sporcle.com">link4</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/chelseafc">link5</a>
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="color:red; font-size: xx-large" ; colspan="5">
        Home Page
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="para">
          <p>Building applications for the internet is a complex and fast-moving field which utilizes a variety of continually evolving technologies. Whether your perspective is from the client or server side, there are many languages
          </p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so what you're doing here is something we used to do back in the 90's before we were really into CSS and things.  Try taking your top menu out of that table and using an unordered list and set the CSS of that list to `list-style: none` and you could use floats or inline-blocks or a personal favorite - flexbox :) https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-nav-bar-fixed-variable-take-rest-elements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is a paragraph in a div in a table cell - unless otherwise specified, div's are block elements, not inline elements.

I see no problem putting the paragraph in the cell (with or without the .para class) and just ignoring the div.

That way, the para should just wrap to the calculated cell width.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set the width of elements:

```
th:first-of-type, .para p {
width: 90px;
}
```

**Complete Example:**

```css
th {
  font-family: "SansSerif";
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: left;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
#table1 {
  border: double;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.para {
  padding: 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

th:first-of-type, .para p {
width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="5px" id="table1">
    <th><a href="http://www.google.ca">link1</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="http://www.last.fm/user/RomeLeader">link2</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="http://www.wolfparade.com">link3</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="http://www.sporcle.com">link4</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/chelseafc">link5</a>
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="color:red; font-size: xx-large" ; colspan="5">
        Home Page
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="para">
          <p>Building applications for the internet is a complex and fast-moving field which utilizes a variety of continually evolving technologies. Whether your perspective is from the client or server side, there are many languages
          </p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to go around would be to move the navigation bar out of the table. Your current layout assumes that the heading is for the for columns in the subsequent rows.

Here's a working example with an unordered list:

http://codepen.io/xvariant/pen/adKVgJ

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "SansSerif";
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: left;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
#table1 {
  border: double;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.para {
  padding: 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">link1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">link2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">link3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">link4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<table align="center" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="5px" id="table1">
  <td align="center" style="color:red; font-size: xx-large" ; colspan="5">
    Home Page
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="para">
        <p>Building applications for the internet is a complex and fast-moving field which utilizes a variety of continually evolving technologies. Whether your perspective is from the client or server side, there are many languages
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
```